# CI/CD pipleline to not allow push of staging URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

So I have a staging URL in my React app to test out the staging features of our website, whenever I am working on a feature we test the feature on the staging URL and then later while pushing to production we update the base URL to production.

```
export const ApiConfigData = {
  STAGING_URL: 'https://app.xyz.io/staging-app/',
  BASE_URL: 'https://app.xyz.io/app/',
};
```

At times staging URL has been pushed to production, as we forgot to update it in ApiConfigData. I was thinking of including a Jest test case to check if the staging URL is being used or not and depending on the result the pipeline would continue.

Can someone help me with the test case, I just want to check if the above staging URL is being used or not. Or if there is some other better way to handle this issue of not pushing the staging URL.

Any advice would be appreciated as I don't have much experience with CI/CD and writing test cases.

Comment: You can add the test case in the jest, make sure you have rule that tells after successful build only we need move forward, incase of build failure at any stage stop the deployment in CI/CD pipeline, and please do share which tool is used to CI/CD

Comment: I am using GitHub Actions for CI/CD. Can you help me with the test case, I just need to check if the variable STAGING_URL is being used or not, I searched for it online that how to check if a variable is used or not in jest but I did not find anything.

Comment: you can use env files to configure, on top of that create new env for each and every environment, guidance link https://dev.to/samirasaad/environment-variables-for-a-react-js-app-329j

Comment: If you're deploying react as a static js code (which is what you should do in most cases for pure UI), env variables won't work. Instead you should do some sort of substitutions at deployment time. Feel free to find me at https://devopscommunity.org/ to chat more.